# Is there an as.Date() equivalent (R) in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

Say we have a string:

```
string = "2014-12-04 04:07:59 <font color='green'> info:</font> One, two, three, four, five."
```

In Python, I'd have to remove everything but `2014-12-04`, then use

```
time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(string, "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple())
```

On the other hand, in R, all I have to do is `as.Date(string)` and I get the appropriate date, in date form. Does Python have something like this?

Comment: You mean apart from `datetime.strptime(string.partition(' ')[0], '%Y-%m-%d'))` ? Not really - you have to pick out what the candidate for a date is (what if there were more than one - not to mention in different formats) then parse it.

Comment: The 3rd party library `dateutil` can help with parsing a date in a wide range of formats -- But the string you pass to it still needs to look like a date.  I don't think it will look for something that looks like a date in the string and then try to parse that.

Comment: @mgilson nope - it still expects the string to contain just a date...

Comment: @JonClements -- Right, that's what I meant by "But the string you pass to it still needs to look like a date".  I guess I should have been more concrete in my next statement ... I _know_ it won't look for something that looks like a date in the string and then try to parse that :-)

Comment: The argument `fuzzy` ignores everything in a string that doesn't look like a date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fuzzy` argument to `dateutil` is used for exactly this purpose:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

string = "2014-12-04 04:07:59 <font color='green'> info:</font> One, two, three, four, five."
dt = parse(string, fuzzy=True)
```

The result is:

```
datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 4, 4, 7, 59)
```

If you just want the date, just use `dt.date()` to return a date object.

Note that if there are other things in the string that could plausibly be part of a date, (e.g. the word `March` or something), that will cause problems for the parser.

If you want to see the things it skipped, use `fuzzy_with_tokens`:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

string = "2014-12-04 04:07:59 <font color='green'> info:</font> One, two, three, four, five."
dt = parse(string, fuzzy=True)

dt, tokens = parse(string, fuzzy_with_tokens=True)
```

`tokens` resolves to:

```
(' ', " <font color='green'> info:</font> One, two, three, four, five.")
```

Answer (score 4):

If you know the location in the string and the date formatting, you can use slicing together with `strptime`:

```
import datetime as dt

>>> dt.datetime.strptime(string[:10], '%Y-%m-%d').date()
datetime.date(2014, 12, 4)
```

If you want to use a package such as pandas:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(string[:10])
Timestamp('2014-12-04 00:00:00')
```

You can also use the [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) package:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

parse(string[:10]).date()
datetime.date(2014, 12, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

To find a date/time in an arbitrary text, you could try [`parsedatetime` module](https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime):

```
>>> import parsedatetime as pdt # $ pip install parsedatetime
>>> text_with_date = "2014-12-04 04:07:59 <font color='green'> info:</font> One, two, three, four, five."
>>> pdt.Calendar().nlp(text_with_date)
((datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 4, 4, 7, 59), 3, 0, 19, '2014-12-04 04:07:59'),)
```

Given a `datetime` object, call `.date()` method, to get only the date part.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is similar thing to as.Date() from (R) in Python. 
Try the following:

```
true_time = pd.to_datetime(your_array, origin ='2000/1/1', unit = 'D')
```

with `origin` you specify the reference date;
with `unit` you specify the specific step (e.g. D - day, ms - milliseconds etc.)
Also in this case, `your_array` can be a list. 
There is also more info [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).